# Battery charging issue with voltage

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, usb, battery-charging

I'm working with this [battery charger IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf) with Vreg = 4.2V.

After the battery is completely charged the green LED is ON.

If I remove the USB and connect it back immediately, the red LED turns ON (indicating that the device is in charging state.)

As per the recharge threshold setting, the device should only start the next cycle of charging after the voltage has dropped to around 3.99V.

Any idea why this is happening if I disconnect and connect the USB immediately?

When the battery is completely charged, instead of 4.2V, it is showing only 4.17V. Any idea why that is?

Comment: _"As per the recharge threshold setting, the device should only start the next cycle of charging after the voltage has dropped to around 3.99V."_ - where does it say that?

Comment: And how would the charger know if battery is fully charged or not, unless it charges it first? Why would it not charge the battery when USB is plugged in? And maybe your multimeter is inaccurate, or the chip is just within 0.7% tolerance.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, checking in the electrical characteristics table on page 6, Automatic recharge threshold, it is given as Vreg-0.21V as minimum value. So, I felt if the voltage goes below 4.2V - 4.21V, then the automatic recharge cycle should start, right?

Comment: @Justme, in that case, if the charger is nearly full, the LED should change from RED to GREEN is sometime quickly right? Also, I agree. It might be the multimeter or the chip tolerance. Let me check that and come back.

Comment: Yes, if charger was disconnected, it does not necessarily know that battery is still full, and your load may have anyway discharged it below limit of starting a charge process. How long does it charge, a few minutes or does it go to charging safety timeout which is a few hours?

Comment: With no load, the charging completes. I again unplug and plug it back. The charging happens for 80 seconds. @Justme. Also, the battery voltage is at 4.17V before the second charging and also 4.17V after charging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per the recharge threshold setting, the device should only start
> the next cycle of charging after the voltage has dropped to around
> 3.99V.

The specification for V<sub>TRH</sub> is V<sub>REF</sub> - 0.21 to -0.09 V, with a typical value of -0.15 V. Assuming V<sub>REF</sub> is exactly 4.2 V that puts V<sub>TRH</sub> at 3.99 to 4.11 V, typically 4.05 V.

However this only applies when charging stops (at 4.2 V) and the battery voltage is going down. If power to the charger is removed and reapplied it resets the controller, which then goes back into charge mode until the battery again reaches 4.2 V.

> When the battery is completely charged, instead of 4.2V, it is showing
> only 4.17V. Any idea why that is?

There are two effects here:-

1. The battery (and wiring/connectors) has resistance, which causes the terminal voltage to be higher due to current flowing through this resistance. When charging stops this voltage drop disappears, revealing the 'true' battery voltage.
2. The battery absorbs some 'surface' charge which initially causes the voltage to rise faster. When charging stops the charge inside the battery slowly evens out, causing the voltage to 'settle'.

As an analogy, imagine a tank connected to another one with a small pipe. You fill one tank with water (which also fills the other one through the pipe, but slower) until it is full. After you stop it continues to fill the other tank while its own level goes down, until both tanks are at the same level (voltage).